# How can I change the button's style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

On a page I'm trying to get the buttons at the top of the page to turn square and blueish. There is a jQuery file for that but for some reason its not working. Here is the following code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("button").button();
 });
```

And the jQuery files:

```
<script src="/jquery_custom/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jquery_custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/jquery_custom/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/jquery_custom/css/fc-blue/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

To the left is the look I'm trying to get, but I keep getting the standard button on the right. What am I doing wrong? (Also the file paths are correct)

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/7E3NR/.  Can you post more code or a jsfiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: I was looking at the source code, and it appears jquery 1.4.2 is being loaded in the head, and then jquery 1.5.2 is being loaded right before closing the body tag. Any particular reason for doing that?

Comment: Building on gilly3's example: http://jsbin.com/ifixo4/  Note how the button function does NOT work with jQuery being loaded in the head and at the end of the body. Then note how it DOES work if you don't load jQuery twice. http://jsbin.com/ifixo4/2

Comment: If I remove the 1.5.2 then the buttons will take on that style but the rest of the page won't work... any ideas?

Comment: in general you should avoid having multiple versions of jQuery and jQueryUI on the same page. It may (as you can see) cause conflicts. If i was you, i would decide which version i want to keep (based on what features i use that are supported by each version) and then rewrite the rest accordingly. That will make future upgrades also possible with relative ease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the markup of how you are defining button the selector could be either:

```
$("button").button();
```

or

```
$("input:submit").button()
```

Can you show us what markup did you use to add buttons?

Just checked the source of your page.

You have jQueryUI custom pack. Are you sure you included button widget in it?

If you check the page errors you'll see

```
Error: $("button").button is not a function
Source File: http://friendsconnect.org/scrapbook-booth/
Line: 25
```

Which means javascript, defining button() method was not loaded. Make sure your custom pack includes the button widget.

You had the startup function written incorrectly. Replace your script with this:

```
$(function () {
    $("button").button();
    $("#radio").buttonset();
    $("input:button").button();
    $("textarea").elastic();

    // Start FriendsConnect rounded corners
    settings = {
        tl: { radius: 5 },
        tr: { radius: 5 },
        bl: { radius: 5 },
        br: { radius: 5 },
        antiAlias: true,
        autoPad: false,
        validTags: ["div"]
    }
    $('#search-main').corner(settings);
    $('#infobox_right').corner(settings);
    // End FriendsConnect rounded corners
  });
```

You now have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Some code
    $(function(){
        //other code
    });
});
```

`$(document).ready(function(){})` and `$(function(){})` are the same and can only (correction: would be nice if it only) appear once on a page

Comment: this is what I used: `<button onclick="user_logout()">Logout</button>` what do you mean by "button widget"?

Comment: jQuery UI consists of Core part, that has general use methods and component widgets (accordion, tabs, progress, button etc...). I did check your pack of jQueryUI and it does have Button widget in it. But i think it's conflicting with something else. Try removing everything except jquery.js, jqueryui.js and jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css (instead removing them just comment the rest of resources out) and try if that works. also add alert("Test") as the first line to $(document).ready() method to check if it will ever fires.

Comment: Also if you look closely you are defining two startup functions: